# AWS account is suspended due non-payment of outstanding balance. Can I pass AWS certificatio

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

Back in 2012 my AWS account credentials ware hacked resulting in a payments I couldn't afford to pay (I was 18 years old that time) and still can't afford. Now I want to take AWS certification. When I login with my email address I can see that I still have Payments due that I have to pay. Would I have problems with non-payment if I register new account and take an AWS certification?

Comment: Why do you create aws accounts if can't afford them? It's just asking for trouble.

Comment: marcin was a 18 years old kid. First year CS student. Wanted to learn how to use AWS, it had a free tier or something that I used.

Comment: Contact to support, request waiver.